# Redundant git server

Tags: git

Is it possible and is it a good idea to have second git server. I want samething like this:

1. user make on his host git push/git pull/any action require remote
2. server if main server is working every thing goes in standard way if
3. main server is down git switch do second server

What is imporant second server shoud syncing with main server.

Comment: I don't particularly like the idea of trying to sync multilple Git servers.  Perhaps GitHub and Bitbucket actually do this.  Although, it might be equally effective to just completely backup your Git server, and, should it fail, you would be in a strong position to spin up another one with minimal effort.

Comment: Use RAID and/or regular backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is inherently de-centralized. That was a core tenet of its design, as [described by Linus Torvalds](https://www.linuxfoundation.org/blog/10-years-of-git-an-interview-with-git-creator-linus-torvalds/) (the creator of git):

> I think that many others had been frustrated by all the same issues that made me hate SCM’s, and while there have been many projects that tried to fix one or two small corner cases that drove people wild, there really hadn’t been anything like git that really ended up taking on the big problems head on. **Even when people don’t realize how important that “distributed” part was (and a lot of people were fighting it), once they figure out that it allows those easy and reliable backups**, and allows people to make their own private test repositories without having to worry about the politics of having write access to some central repository, they’ll never go back.
>
> *(Emphasis mine)*

*You can also [watch a talk Linus gave on Git](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8&t=12m26s), specifically about the importance of the distributed nature of git, at Google in 2007.*

Basically, your local repo **is** a backup of your server. If your server goes down, you can spin up a new one based on your local repo.

As far as having multiple servers... sure, it's possible, and it might make you feel better. You could set up the second server to have an "origin" pointing to the main server, and the main server with an "origin" point to the second server, and just run `git fetch` at regular intervals on each. The logistics of merging aren't terribly complicated... each of your servers is acting kind of like another developer. You might have some confusion about source of truth should they ever diverge or have conflicts, but you could resolve those as long as you are diligent about it. But you wouldn't have anything that you don't already have on every developer's machine, and you'd probably be better off just backing up the server at regular intervals. There's no *problem* with that approach... it's just a bit unnecessary and redundant.

Answer (score 5):

You can add multiple urls using "pushurl".

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://original/repository.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://another/failover_repository.git
```

So when you push to origin, it will push to both repositories, this way different repositories are always sync.

Comment: This is useful to keep a second push server. However, be aware the note from Mark Adelsberger about the remotes becoming out-of-sync in a non-trivial dev environment. This works great as long as both servers are always up or you never push distinct commits to the backup server. If the main server is down and you push commits to the backup, then a user clones and pushes to the main (never seeing the additional commits to the backup), you now potentially have to manually fix the differences down-the-line. Git is awesomely decentralized but go too far down this line and the merges become painful.

Comment: What happens if push to one of the remotes fails ? I mean push to original/repository.git is succesful but another/failover_repository.git fails.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic failover capability built into git.  When you `push`, `fetch`, or `pull`, git is going to settle on one URL to try.  This is often determined by the configuration of your remotes, but nonetheless...

So for the actual failover you describe to happen, you need something outside git.  That could be a client-side script, or it could be built into your hosting solution.  You didn't mention how your repo is hosted, but for example if it is on a web server then you could use a load balancer to route requests among available nodes, with failover in the event that one fails.  Whether you could configure this such that one node is always used unless it fails is a server-specific configuration question.

But if you do this, and the repos fall out of sync even temporarily (which they will in any nontrivial development environment), then you risk having major usability problems.  I push commit `A` to the primary remote, but just as I'm finishing (and before it can sync with the secondary), it goes offline.  Now the secondary takes over, but doesn't have that change *even though the remote tracking branch from my local - which is now implicitly mapped to it - says that it does*.  And that's just a simple case of what can go wrong.

So... is it possible?  Probably.  Is it a good idea?  No.  I can think of no application where HA practices for a source control repo are worth the headaches this will likely cause.

Comment: ^ Important, just syncing to two distinct remotes will go out-of-sync and be a major headache if you only sync to one or sync differently to the backup. Commits are played on top of specific commits so this chain needs to be identical between the servers. There may be some more advanced git functionality to get around this or merge down the differences?